# fig,ax=plt.subplots can not show figuer in right position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use matplotlib.pyplot,subplots to show some figuers but the position of the figuers are not right, they always pile up on the last subfiguer, I don't know why.
Here is my code.

```
fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)=plt.subplots(1,4,figsize=(20,5))
ax1=plt.scatter(SenRev(data1959)[:,0],SenRev(data1959)[:,1])
ax2=plt.scatter(SenRev(data1979)[:,0],SenRev(data1979)[:,1])
ax3=plt.scatter(SenRev(data1999)[:,0],SenRev(data1999)[:,1])
ax4=plt.scatter(SenRev(data2019)[:,0],SenRev(data2019)[:,1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Call the `scatter` method on each of the axes

```
ax1.scatter(SenRev(data1959)[:,0],SenRev(data1959)[:,1])
ax2.scatter(SenRev(data1979)[:,0],SenRev(data1979)[:,1])
ax3.scatter(SenRev(data1999)[:,0],SenRev(data1999)[:,1])
ax4.scatter(SenRev(data2019)[:,0],SenRev(data2019)[:,1])
```